# Как выводит лог для отдельного класса в spring MVC c помощью log4j?

Tags: spring, mvc

Всем привет. Ребят подскажите как организовать ведения лога для отдельного класса. Я понимаю как можно сделать общий логгер для всего приложения, а как для конкретного класса запутался. Не понятно как указать сам логер, что бы тот выводил информацию в определенный файл.

Answer (score 0):

```
log4j.properties

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:\\....\log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p 
%c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Так создаете логгер в нужном классе:

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Classname.class);
```